# tokens error in css file

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx, fxml

Whenever i create a css file either by web->css or by javafx project i get the same error

```
    Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", interface expected
    - Syntax error, insert "InterfaceBody" to complete CompilationUnit
```

i searched for the solutions but they are generally like create a new css file by web->css but that didn't help me.
i further researched and i found that there is no output file for css in bin.Now i don't know what to do.Can anyone help me?
here is my code(eclipse Neon):

```
   package application;

   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;
   import javafx.scene.Parent;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        System.out.println("aaaa");
        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setTitle("pvrock");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

application.css

```
#label{
     -fx-font-size:30px;

 }
```

Main.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


     <AnchorPane prefHeight="300" prefWidth="400" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" fx:controller="application.MainController">
       <children>
          <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="169.0" layoutY="198.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#f1" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Click me">
     <font>
        <Font size="10.0" />
     </font>
  </Button>
  <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="146.0" layoutY="112.0" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

MainController.java

```
    package application;

    import java.util.Random;

    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainController {
@FXML
private Label label;

public void f1(ActionEvent event){
    Random rand=new Random();
    int num=rand.nextInt(50)+1;
    System.out.println(num);
    label.setText(Integer.toString(num));

}

}
```

screenshot of errors: 
[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxEpS.png)

[errors in application.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB5fv.png)

Comment: There is no compilation error seen in the screenshot

Comment: sorry runtime error